# Predict y value for a given x in R

Tags: r, linear-regression, predict

I have a linear model:

```
mod=lm(weight~age, data=f2)
```

I would like to input an age value and have returned the corresponding weight from this model. This is probably simple, but I have not found a simple way to do this.

Comment: There is a `predict` method for `lm`, and you have to supply the new data as `newdata` argument. Look here: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/predict.lm.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your purposes are related to just one prediction you can just grab your coefficient with

```
coef(mod)
```

Or you can just build a simple equation like this.

```
coef(mod)[1] + "Your_Value"*coef(mod)[2]
```

Comment: Is this truly the most concise way to do this? Can `predict()` not do this, without creating a whole new `data.frame`?

Answer (score 10):

Its usually more robust to use the predict method of `lm`:

```
f2<-data.frame(age=c(10,20,30),weight=c(100,200,300))
f3<-data.frame(age=c(15,25))
mod<-lm(weight~age,data=f2)
pred3<-predict(mod,f3)
```

This spares you from wrangling with all of the coefs when the models can be potentially large.